# What software can enlarge my webcam on Skype?

Tags: windows, gratis, skype

I use Skype software installed on Windows 10 laptop. Currently when I video-chat with someone, my webcam (red arrow) is teeny. I prefer free 3rd party software that can enlarge it.

[image]

I prefer something like a split screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that might help:

- [Skype on Windows](https://blogs.skype.com/tips/2014/09/18/how-to-adjust-video-size-on-skype-group-calls/)
- [Skype on PC or Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Resize-a-Skype-Video-Chat-on-PC-or-Mac)

You might also try dragging & dropping the small image of your own video feed into the center of the call screen, which should trigger a side-by-side view of both video feeds (yours & the other participant) at an equal size. [Reference Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_mac-skype_callms-skype_audioms/how-to-make-yourself-bigger-on-a-skype-video-call/f8821770-2798-429b-9a47-289038dc0ebb?page=2)

Comment: "You might also try dragging & dropping the small image of your own video feed into the center of the call screen, which should trigger a side-by-side view of both video feeds" : I tried this, but this failed.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal can you indicate what failed? And are you sure you're on the right Skype version (Skype for Desktop 8)?

Comment: Hey @GroupTheory You commented with the wrong account.